# When I invoke pop function on the stack the total sum becomes total sum of the elements in the list before pop + total sum of the list after pop

Tags: python-3.x, list, stack

Below are the conditions I am trying to meet:

1. we want the push method not only to push the value onto the stack but also to add the value to the sum variable;
2. we want the pop function not only to pop the value off the stack but also to subtract the value from the sum variable.

1st one is done but second one I thought it will give the sum of the latest list post the pop function was invoked on the stack. Can someone explain why am I getting this output and what could be done to get the expected output.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__stack_list = []
        
    def push(self, val):
        self.__stack_list.append(val)
        
    def pop(self):
        val = self.__stack_list[-1]
        del self.__stack_list[-1]
        return val
    

class AddingStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self):
        Stack.__init__(self)
        self.__sum = 0
        
    def add(self):
        for i in self._Stack__stack_list:
            if i in self._Stack__stack_list:
                self.__sum = self.__sum + i
        return self.__sum
    
stack_object = Stack()


stack_object = AddingStack()

stack_object.push(3)
stack_object.push(6)
stack_object.push(10)
print(stack_object._Stack__stack_list)
print(stack_object.add())
stack_object.pop()
print(stack_object._Stack__stack_list)
print(stack_object.add())
```

Output:
[3, 6, 10]
19
[3, 6]
28

Expected output should be:
[3, 6, 10]
19
[3, 6]
9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are initialising the `__sum` when you are creating the object of AddingStack class. Therefore, once you call the method `stack_object.add()`, the `__sum` value gets changed from 0 to the sum of the values in the list and never reset to 0 again.

To overcome this issue, do not create the class variable, instead create a local variable in your add function and return it.

```
def add(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in self._Stack__stack_list:
            if i in self._Stack__stack_list:
                sum = sum + i
        return sum
```